# Return/save values from AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, return, android-alertdialog

So, I've got this code for an AlertDialog in an Android activity, and although it works and pops up at the correct moment, when I press the "OK" buttons it's supposed to save the 2 variables which I put in, into 2 Strings which after the activity should be able to use those strings.

```
private void showDialog(){
AlertDialog.Builder alertdg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
alertdg.setTitle("Choose page");
alertdg.setMessage("Choose episode/page");

final EditText page = new EditText(this); 
final EditText episode = new EditText(this); 
page.setWidth(210); 
episode.setWidth(210); 

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 

layout.addView(episode); 
layout.addView(page); 
alertdg.setView(layout); 

alertdg.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        episodeString = episode.getText().toString();
        pageString = page.getText().toString(); 
    }
});

alertdg.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
alertdg.show(); 
}
```

And yes if you're wondering I already declared the 2 strings "episodeString" and "pageString" somewhere in the start of the activity, and I know I declared them correctly. Now what I'm wondering is, why can't I return those values so that the rest of the activity can use them? I've tried many times but the Dialog just won't return/save values... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debug this portion of code? if yes have you printed the values after onClick. i am assuming there is problem in OnClick only

Comment: Well you are doing everything right. So technically your code should work. Can you tell me how / when you are accessing those variables, and where exactly have you defined them.
And like @Drax said, try logging the values in the onClickListener , make sure you are getting the values there atleast.

Comment: I think i know what you are trying to do, Are you trying to use those Variables as soon as you call `showDialog`? See, the variables are filled with values ONLY after the OK button is pushed, until then they are empty. I hope this solves this.

Comment: Oh, Sidenote, `showDialog(int)` is an internal Activity function, It'll be confusing later, maybe you should rename it.

Comment: LOL I'm such an idiot, I put the episodeString and pageString inside double quotes when I called the two variables from another method... therefor instead of saying (for instance) 20 + 50, it said episodeString + pageString...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code absolutely works

```
package pete.android.study;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private String mEpisode = "";
    private String mPage = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        showDialog();

    }

    private void showDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertdg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
        alertdg.setTitle("Choose page");
        alertdg.setMessage("Choose episode/page");

        final EditText page = new EditText(this); 
        final EditText episode = new EditText(this); 
        page.setWidth(210); 
        episode.setWidth(210); 

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 

        layout.addView(episode); 
        layout.addView(page); 
        alertdg.setView(layout); 

        alertdg.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mEpisode = episode.getText().toString();
                mPage = page.getText().toString(); 

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mEpisode + " | " + mPage,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alertdg.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        alertdg.show();


    }


}
```